# weird flutter installation error appearing

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

installed flutter according to the documentation and also added the bin folder path to the environment variables, then i runed flutter doctor and got this

```
C:\Users\Mohammed\Desktop\flutter\flutter>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 0.0.0-unknown, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2861], locale en-US)
    ! Flutter version 0.0.0-unknown on channel stable at
      C:\Users\Mohammed\Downloads\flutter_windows_3.13.9-stable\flutter
      Cannot resolve current version, possibly due to local changes.
      Reinstall Flutter by following instructions at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install.
    ! Upstream repository unknown source is not a standard remote.
      Set environment variable "FLUTTER_GIT_URL" to unknown source to dismiss this error.
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.2.5)
    X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop
      development with C++" workload, and include these components:
        MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
         - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
        C++ CMake tools for Windows
        Windows 10 SDK
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

but running it in the bin folder returns this

```
C:\Users\Mohammed\Desktop\flutter\flutter\bin>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2861], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.2.5)
    X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop
      development with C++" workload, and include these components:
        MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
         - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
        C++ CMake tools for Windows
        Windows 10 SDK
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

due to this i cant run `flutter --version` or `flutter pub get` on vscode because of this error

```
PS C:\Users\Mohammed\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\myflutter_assignment> flutter pub get
Resolving dependencies... (1.0s)
The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.

Because myflutter_assignment depends on go_router >=0.2.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.17.0, version solving failed.


You can try the following suggestion to make the pubspec resolve:
* Try using the Flutter SDK version: 3.16.5.



PS C:\Users\Mohammed\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\myflutter_assignment> flutter --version
Flutter • channel stable • unknown source
Framework • revision  () • 1970-01-01 03:00:00.000
Engine • revision 0545f8705d
Tools • Dart 3.1.5 • DevTools 2.25.0
```

can somebody help me fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have 2 different flutter installations. One at

```
C:\Users\Mohammed\Downloads\flutter_windows_3.13.9-stable\flutter
```

and the other at

```
C:\Users\Mohammed\Desktop\flutter\flutter
```

And the first one is corrupted somehow and in your PATH and the second one is correct but isn't in your PATH.

So you need to correct the PATH. (and possibly just delete your flutter installations at the first location). How to correct your PATH you can read at https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows/desktop?tab=download or to quote:

> Press Windows + S.
>
> Type environment.
>
> When Edit the system environment variables displays as the Best match,
> click Open under Edit the system environment variables.
>
> Click About.
>
> Click Advanced System Settings.
>
> Click Environment Variables…
>
> The Environment Variables dialog displays.
>
> Under User variables for  check for the Path entry.
>
> If the entry exists, click Edit….
>
> If the entry doesn’t exist, click New….
>
> Click New.
>
> Type \flutter\bin.
>
> Click the \flutter\bin entry.
>
> Click Move Up until the Flutter entry sits at the top of the list.
>
> Click OK.
>
> To enable these changes, close and reopen any existing command prompts
> and PowerShell instances.